# Setting a custom processStrategy in the Spring Camel file component throws Could not find a suitable setter for property: processStrategy

Tags: apache-camel, spring-camel, camel-file, apache-camel-file

I'm trying to set a custom processStrategy in Camel 2.23.2. I've tried several ways to reference it from the [processStrategy uri parameter](https://camel.apache.org/components/2.x/file-component.html#_query_parameters_87_parameters), but I always get this exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find a suitable setter for property: processStrategy as there isn't a setter method with same type: java.lang.String nor type conversion possible: No type converter available to convert from type: java.lang.String to the required type: org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileProcessStrategy with value #genericFileNoOpProcessStrategy"
```

Route definition

```
    <bean id="genericFileNoOpProcessStrategy" class="org.apache.camel.component.file.strategy.GenericFileNoOpProcessStrategy"/>
    <routeContext id="routes" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
        <route id="route">
            <from uri="seda:someEvent"/>
            <pollEnrich>
                <constant>file:/folder?fileName=file.csv&amp;processStrategy=#genericFileNoOpProcessStrategy"</constant>
            </pollEnrich>
```

What's the right way to reference it?

Answer (score 0):

This would've been working if it weren't a user error (notice the quote `"`):

```
<constant>file:/folder?fileName=file.csv&amp;processStrategy=#genericFileNoOpProcessStrategy"</constant>
```

Fixed with:

```
<constant>file:/folder?fileName=file.csv&amp;processStrategy=#genericFileNoOpProcessStrategy"</constant>
```